# confusion regarding *(asterisk) and ++ in c

Tags: c, pointers, operators

```
int main()
{
  int a=10;
  int *b=&a;
  int c=*b++;
  printf("%d",c);
}
```

I know following program outputs 10.but according to precedence table which gives precedence of operator http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) ,post-fix ++ has higher precedence than = and *.so ++ should evaluate first and then *.then why program is printing output as 10?

Comment: Maybe you meant to try this: `int c = (*b)++;` (prints 10) versus `int c = ++(*b);` (prints 11).  In both cases, `a` becomes 11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does have higher precedence, which means the pointer will get increased by one, not the value it points to.

But the increase by one is sequenced to the end of the evaluation( that is what postfix ++ does, and that is not directly related to precedence ), so the value you get out of the pointer is the old one: `p` not `p+1`. Having that pointer, you dereference it and get the value of a, which is 10. Then the pointer `p` is incremented by one.

```
int c = *p ;
p++ ;
```

Answer (score 0):

`++` has higher precedence than `*` means operand `b` will bind to `++` first as

```
 int c = *(b++);
```

It doesn't mean in any way that evaluate `b++` first and then dereference the evaluated value. 
In `*b++`, `++` will have the same effect on `b` as that post increment operator do. `*b++` is simply: Dereference original value of `b` and increment the pointer `b` by `1`.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, `++` has higher precedence than `*`. So `int c=*b++;` parses as `int c=*(b++);`. However, the result of the post-increment operator is the value **before** incrementing. In other words, the assignment is equivalent to

```
int temp = b;
b = b + 1;
c = *temp;
```

Comment: Assignment may also equivalent to `int temp = b; c = *temp; b = b + 1;`.

Comment: @haccks Certainly. I think the way I wrote it is clearer in the current context since the first two lines are equivalent to the post-increment. The lack of proximity in your version blurs this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `++` will do an increment of `b`, a memory address, after evaluation in the context of the larger expression.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1e3921c.aspx:

> It is important to note that a postfix increment or decrement expression evaluates to the value of the expression prior to application of the respective operator. The increment or decrement operation occurs after the operand is evaluated. This issue arises only when the postfix increment or decrement operation occurs in the context of a larger expression.

So, what happens is that you apply a post-fix increment to `b`, but the dereference `*` is given the original value of `b`, which points to `10`. If you were to print out `b` or `*b` you'll see that the value and address have changed to something unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ++ has higher precedence than *.
So, the statement

```
int c=*b++;
```

will be evaluated as

```
int c=*(b++)
```

Since it's post-fix operator, the pointer 'b'  is incremented first, but it returns the old address of 'b'(which points to address storing the value  10 ).
Therefore, c will have the value 10.