# Won't the order of evaluation fail to copy source string to destination string in the given user defined function?

Tags: c, string, pointers, operator-keyword, operator-precedence

```
void mystrcat(char* dest,char* src)
{
    while(*dest) dest++;
    while(*dest++=*src++);
    return;
}
```

The above block of code is an user-defined function to copy the contents of a string to the end of another string.
Here, we walk through the destination string until it hits the null character `'\0'`. The 2nd while loop is supposedly used to copy the contents the source string to the end of destination string.

I have read that an expression such as, `*ptr++` is evaluated as `*(ptr++)`according to the precedence table of operators in C.
If that is the case shouldn't the expression: `*dest++=*src++` be evaluated as
`*(dest++)=*(src++)` ?
Wouldn't that cause dest to first point to the next location in the memory and updating its value rather than, updating `'\0'` with a character from the source string? Similarly, won't it cause `src` to miss the 1st character of the source string?

However, the function seems to be successful in copying the contents of the source string to the end of the destination string.

Comment: after execution of the first while loop, you've reached a NUL byte, so you shouldn't be incrementing `dest`

Comment: `NULL` is a macro with a ___null pointer constant___, not a character. You mean either ASCII `NUL` or a _null character_ or `'\0'` or `0`.

Comment: @Olaf I meant the null character '\0'. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: It was not ambiguous, but simply wrong. Just keep it in mind!

Comment: @RyanMcCullagh Exactly! That's the point. This function should not work.

Comment: @Olaf I will keep that in mind. Thank you!

Comment: @RyanMcCullagh: Please provide a reference to the standard disallowing this. As it looks the code is fine (assuming `dest` has enough space, of course).

Comment: @barmar: Your edit changed the question significantly. It is not clear it was just a typo! You should have asked for clarification before editing.

Comment: @Olaf I think it's quite clear that he meant to put his C code into the text, and he didn't realize that `*` has special meaning in markup.

Comment: @Barmar: Sorry, I did not check the mark**down** ;-) source code, just the rendered text. Objection withdrawn

Comment: On second read: There is no specific "order of evaluation".

Answer (score 1):

With the postfix `++` operator the operand is incremented *after* it is evaluated in the current context.  In this expression, the current value of `dest` is dereferenced and the location assigned to, and the current value of `src` is dereferenced and the value assigned to the left hand side.

From section 6.5.2.4 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> *2* **The  result  of  the  postfix `++` operator  is  the  value  of  the  operand.**  As  a  side  effect,  the value of the operand object
>   is incremented (that is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is added 
>   to  it).   See  the  discussions  of  additive  operators  and 
>   compound  assignment  for information  on  constraints,  types,  and 
>   conversions  and  the  effects  of  operations  on pointers.   **The 
>   value  computation  of  the  result  is  sequenced  before  the  side 
>   effect  of updating  the  stored  value  of  the  operand.**  With 
>   respect  to  an  indeterminately-sequenced function call, the
>   operation of postfix `++` is a single evaluation.  Postfix `++` on an
>   object with  atomic  type  is  a  read-modify-write  operation  with
>   `memory_order_seq_cst` memory order semantics.

So this:

```
*dest++=*src++
```

Is (roughly) the same as:

```
*dest=*src;
dest+=1;
src+=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing is that `*dest++` uses **post**-increment. That means the expression `dest++` returns the value from before it was incremented, and this is the pointer we dereference with `*`. So it assigns to the current location in memory, then increments the pointer.

```
*dest++ = *src++;
```

is effectively equivalent to:

```
*dest = *src;
dest++;
src++;
```

The problem you describe would happen if you instead wrote:

```
*(++dest) = *(++src);
```

because pre-increment increments the variable and evaluates to the new value, which is the next location.

See [What is the difference between ++i and i++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i)

Comment: @TirthaSarathiGhosh Since post-increment has higher precedence it's equivalent to `*(dest++)`. If dereferencing had higher precedence it would be equivalent to `(*dest)++`

Comment: Sorry my use of parentheses was wrong. The evaluation should be *(dest++) instead of (*dest)++ since, post-increment has higher precedence.

Comment: @TirthaSarathiGhosh And that's exactly what it is. That's what you wrote in the question.

Comment: Please reread the last few points of the question. I clearly stated that evaluation of *(dest++) instead of (*dest)++ would cause dest to first point to the next location in the memory and updating its value rather than, updating '\0' with a character from the source string.

Comment: I explained why that's not true in my answer. `dest++` is evaluated first, but its value is the OLD value of `dest`. Then we dereference the old value with `*`, so we update the current location, not the next location.

Comment: Ah! Got it! Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to note that a postfix increment or decrement expression evaluates to the value of the expression prior to application of the respective operator. The increment or decrement operation occurs after the operand is evaluated. See: [Postfix Increment and Decrement Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1e3921c.aspx) and [confusion regarding *(asterisk) and ++ in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742536/confusion-regarding-asterisk-and-in-c)